# javascript toUpperCase not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox

Currently I am trying to force uppercase in a textbox in a javascript method.  This method is set to be called on a 'keypress' event to go into a textbox.

Here is my method to change to uppercase with IE and FF detection.

```
          //some code to detect the kind of key pressed based on numeric value, 
          //if lowercase detected then continue

        var key; 
        if(window.event){ //working IE code                     
                //key = window.event.keyCode;
                window.event.keyCode-=32;
        }

        else if(e){ //broken FF code
                key = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toUpperCase()
                e.value = e.value.toUpperCase();
        }
```

This current code says e.value is undefined in firebug.  If i try just e.toUpperCase() firebug says toUpperCase does not exist.  I have tried setting e.value equal to 'key', which returns no errors but does not change to uppercase.  I have tried directly changing e.which but of course, that is read only and returns an error saying such.

What exactly am I missing here?  I believe that the problem is no matter what I change here, e.which is STILL set as the lowercase value, and because I can't edit it in any way, the original lowercase e.which character is getting pushed to the textbox.

Comment: You're trying to change the key by updating the "value" property of the event object? Is that right?

Comment: according to this code, yes.  Is that incorrect?  is the 'value' property not the key that was pressed?

Comment: There's no "value" attribute, according to the W3C spec and the Mozilla documentation. There's a "key" attribute, but it's read-only.

Comment: ok, so then what do I alter in order to change the case?  Everything I'm seeing about firefox is that all the things I need to change are read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do this another way:

```
function keypressHandler() {
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
}

document.getElementById('whatever').onkeypress = keypressHandler;
// or use addEventListener or whatever
```

*edit* actually it works a little better with the following hack:

```
function keypressHandler(event) {
    var inp = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        inp.value = inp.value.toUpperCase();
    }, 0);
}
```

That lets the key that caused the event get added to the value before the value is "fixed".

The point is that handling keyboard events is pretty messy and things vary between browsers. The approach above avoids that entirely by simply working directly on the value, which is maintained by the browser.

*edit* — note that for the code here to work, the event handler has to be set up the way this code does it.  If you set it in the "onkeypress" attribute in the HTML markup, it'd have to be different:

```
<input onkeypress='keypressHandler.call(this)'>
```

Comment: inp.value = inp.value.toUpperCase(); is essentually doing the exact same thing I already am, and thus produces the same 'inp.value' is undefined error.

Comment: No, it's not the same - `inp` in my code is a reference to the `<input>` DOM element, not the event. [And it works just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ngny9/)

Comment: So then why am I getting a 'inp.value' or 'this.value' or 'e.value' is undefined error when attempting to use toUpperCase() ?  Your code is editing text.  In my case, the event.which.  And yes, I can do the same thing.  The problem is I'm left with a inp.value that is uppercase but the original input character is still lowercase.

Comment: You're probably setting up the event handler differently than in the code I posted. You didn't post that so I don't know for sure.

Comment: its currently set as 'onkeypress'      Me.txtData.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return NT_TextControls_ValidateUpper(this,event);")

Comment: @Pointy: Don't use a `keypress` handler for that, then you won't need a timeout.

Comment: @Bergi really?  Hmm ... is the "value" attribute updated for the others ("keyup" I guess)?  Well I can of course just try it :-)

Comment: @Pointy <input name="txtINPUT_LicenseNumber_text" type="text" maxlength="20" size="30" id="txtINPUT_LicenseNumber_text" class="bigtext" onblur="return NT_TextControls_OnBlur(this,event);" name="txtINPUT_LicenseNumber_text" onfocus="javascript:this.select();" onkeyup="return NT_TextControls_ValidateUpper(this,event);" /></td>
Is the set up for the eventhandler.  ValidateUpper is the method I posted.  Since I do in fact use onkeyup, what changes need to be made in your code?  Because honestly.. my code looks pretty similar to your suggestion.

Comment: The key thing is to make sure that the function has access to the DOM element; the event is not important here.  You can pass `this` as an explicit parameter or you can use `.call()`.

Comment: Yes, so how do I get access to the DOM element?  What am I missing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z2KDm/2/ full code.  Says it checks out on that page, but it doesn't work.  says keycode.toUpperCase() is not a function

Comment: @JesseDurham well the value of `keycode` is absolutely not the correct thing.  All you need is `myfield.value = myfield.value.toUpperCase()` - the event and the keycode are totally unimportant.  Both Bergi and I posted jsfiddle examples for you to copy.

Comment: @Pointy ok, I'm getting closer.  Your myfield.value change does alter the text to uppercase.. but only AFTER a new letter is keyed, and otherwise stays lowercase until then.  Bergi posted a link about that in his post though.. so on the right track.

Comment: @JesseDurham ah yes Bergi's using "keyup" instead of "keypress" I think and that works better.

Comment: @Pointy I am using keyup.  But I just tried both methods and they both produce the same result.  The last letter not changing until a new one is input.  I will continue to run through this, but I am definitely getting closer.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

[KeyEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/KeyboardEvent) have no `value` property. You might want to use [this snippet](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#key) to detect the keys, and you also might want to read about [Detecting keystrokes](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html).

Also note that event properties are (in general) read-only. You would need to prevent the current event trigger an extra one with a different key.

To uppercase everything typed in an `<input>` element, you don't need to alter key events. Just change the value of the input itself after the characters appeared. You will need to listen on the `keyup` instead of the `keypress` event for that ([read why](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)):

```
inputEl.onkeyup = function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
};
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Ngny9/1/)). It is simple and works in all browsers, the only drawback is that it does not immidiately uppercase when you insert more then one character by holding a key ([workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/Ngny9/2/)).

Comment: IE lets me modify the window.event.keycode value directly.  I am detecting they keystroke fine.  I need to alter what was pressed for Firefox.

Comment: Internet Explorer != Firefox. Firefox follows the W3C spec (well mostly) and according to that the event fields are read-only.

Comment: I understand that.  But it still doesn't answer my question on how I can edit the value to uppercase in firefox.

Comment: Interesting, Ok I'll see how handling the keyup event works. *Edit* No change.. I think I should make the point that my 'onkeypress' detection is handled as an attribute for the textbox set in VB.  Its not (as far as I know and I could be wrong) coming in as <Input> in html

Comment: The inputs for the textbox are...       <input name="txtINPUT_LicenseNumber_text" type="text" maxlength="20" size="30" id="txtINPUT_LicenseNumber_text" class="bigtext" onblur="return NT_TextControls_OnBlur(this,event);" name="txtINPUT_LicenseNumber_text" onfocus="javascript:this.select();" onkeyup="return NT_TextControls_ValidateUpper(this,event);" /></td>  ValidateUpper is the method I posted

Comment: The fiddle worksforme, also in FF. Of course you need to adapt your event handler code, you can't use `this` as a reference to the input element. You should use JS-only [event handler registration](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html)!

Comment: Everyone seems to be ignoring the fact I get 'this.value' is undefined when I attempt these changes.  Why?

Comment: No, I'm not ignoring it. It depends on your handler registration model, and I stronly recommend not to use html attributes. Just get a reference to your input element to change its `value` property. You could e.g. use `document.getElementById("txtINPUT_LicenseNumber_text")`...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.. but how does getting the value in document.getElementById("txtINPUT_LicenseNumber_text") actually change the key pressed?  I would still run into the same problem of not editing the actual key that was pressed...  Or am I just completely misunderstanding what you are saying?

Comment: It does not change the key you pressed, because a computer cannot change what you do/did (the reason why event props are readonly). Instead it just changes the resulting value of the input element after you inserted something.

Comment: right, I understand that.  What I'm saying is, if I have something like.. key = document.getElementById("txtINPUT_LicenseNumber_text") then i alter the 'key' value.  I don't actually change anything.  The value stored at document.getElementById("txtINPUT_LicenseNumber_text") is still a lowercase value regardless of how much i fool around with the 'key' variable.So how do I effectively change what the textbox receives.

Comment: Reassign it, as in our code snippets. `var el=document.getElementById("..."); var string = el.value.toUpperCase(); el.value = string`